# MySQL Workbench export alter script truncates comments

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using Workbench v5.2.44 CE.

When I run an export ALTER script command, all comments are truncated no matter what the length of the text is.
Example :

> ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable
>    CHANGE COLUMN `type` `type` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL COMMENT ' /* comment truncated */' ;

This is not the case when exporting to a create script.
I have not been able to find where I can change this behaviour.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Try to write a comment with characters number isn't greater than 60.

Comment: @AlbertoLeón all my comments are less than 60 characters. They are still truncated systematically.  As I stated before, the comments are not truncated when exporting to a create script.